# How do I configure this database.json file so that my app's api connects to a database

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, npm, npm-install

I'm banging my head against a wall right now trying to get this app I cloned up and running. Here is the database.json file I'm working with:

```js
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "crate",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "seederStorage": "sequelize"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "crate",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "seederStorage": "sequelize"
  }
}
```

here's the config.json file

```
{
  "url": {
    "api": "http://my-ip-address:8000"
  },
  "message": {
    "error": {
      "timers": {
        "short": 1000,
        "default": 2000,
        "long": 4000
      }
    }
  },
  "product": {
    "types": {
      "cloth": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cloth"
      },
      "accessory": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Accessories"
      }
    }
  },
  "user": {
    "gender": {
      "male": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Male"
      },
      "female": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Female"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I run `npm run setup:api`, like the readme says to do, it crashes when it starts running the Sequelize CLI

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.18.3, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.6]

Loaded configuration file "src\config\database.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@1.0.0 db:migrate: `sequelize db:migrate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 db:migrate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-08T00_45_25_767Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@1.0.0 setup:db: `npm run db:migrate && npm run db:seed`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 setup:db script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-08T00_45_25_808Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! api@1.0.0 setup: `npm run setup:install && npm run setup:db`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the api@1.0.0 setup script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-08T00_45_25_857Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! crate@1.0.0 setup:api: `npm run setup --prefix api`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crate@1.0.0 setup:api script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm running Windows 10, Node v12.18.3, through Visual Studio v1.47.3

If anyone can help I'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to setup a mysql database on your device. There are multiple applications you can use for this. Personally I use the database that comes with [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). After you setup XAMPP or any other database application, you'll have to create a database named `crate`.

Comment: so I just used the mysql workbench to create a mysql connection called "crate", but despite that, the sequelize CLI returns `ERROR: Unknown database 'crate'`

Comment: You have to create a database called `crate`.  You can follow the following tutorial to do so: [https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-mysql-database-workbench](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-mysql-database-workbench).

Comment: Thanks! That did it!